# Getting "Not Applicable" compile error with generic type

Tags: java, oop, generics

I have the following classes:

```
public interface IEntity<T extends IEntity<T>>
{
   T createNewEntity(IEntityCreator creator);
}

public interface IEntityCreator
{
   <T extends IEntity<T>> T createNewEntity(T source);
}

public abstract class EntityBase<T extends EntityBase<T>> implements IEntity<T>
{
   @Override
   public T createNewEntity(IEntityCreator creator)
   {
      return creator.createNewEntity(this); //Error here
   }
}
```

I get the following error:

"Bound mismatch: The generic method createNewEntity(T) of type IEntityCreator is not applicable for the arguments (EntityBase). The inferred type EntityBase is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter >"

I tried a different approach with the following code with no success:

```
public interface IEntity<T extends IEntity<T>>
{
   T createNewEntity(IEntityCreator<T> creator);
}

public interface IEntityCreator<T extends IEntity<T>>
{
   T createNewEntity(T source);
}

public abstract class EntityBase<T extends EntityBase<T>> implements IEntity<T>
{
   @Override
   public T createNewEntity(IEntityCreator<T> creator)
   {
      return creator.createNewEntity(this); //Error here
   }
}
```

This time the compiler says:

"The method createNewEntity(T) in the type IEntityCreator is not applicable for the arguments (EntityBase)"

What is the cause for this error? How can I correct it?

Thanks

Comment: Your first line: public interface IEntity<T extends IEntity<T>>. You forgot a ">" after IEntity<T

Comment: try replase `T` to `EntityBase<T>` in `EntityBase.createNewEntity` declaration

Comment: How replace with `return creator.createNewEntity((T)this);` ???

Answer (score 0):

Pretty extrange pattern here, but this compiles...

```
public interface IEntity<T extends EntityBase<T>>
{
   T createNewEntity(IEntityCreator<T> creator);
}

public interface IEntityCreator<T extends EntityBase<T>>
{
   T createNewEntity(EntityBase<T> entityBase);
}

public abstract class EntityBase<T extends EntityBase<T>> implements IEntity<T>
{
   @Override
   public T createNewEntity(IEntityCreator<T> creator)
   {
      return creator.createNewEntity(this); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause for error is that `IEntityCreator.createNewEntity()` needs a `T` which implements `IEntity<T>`, and you are passing `EntityBase<T>`, so it should implement `IEntity<EntityBase<T>>`, which it doesn't do.

You need to explicitly cast `this` to `T` (a derived class from `EntityBase<T>` which actually implements `IEntity<T>`), like Wundwin Born suggested in comments:

```
public T createNewEntity(IEntityCreator creator) {
    return creator.createNewEntity((T)this);
}
```